# Ansible from ppa won't install python-related packages

Tags: apt, package-management, python, ppa, debian

When I build my dockerfile, which does the following:

```
FROM debian:jessie
...
RUN echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list \
    && apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 93C4A3FD7BB9C367 \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install ansible
```

I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ansible : Depends: python-jinja2 but it is not installable
           Depends: python but it is not installable
           Depends: python-yaml but it is not installable
           Depends: python-paramiko but it is not installable
           Depends: python-httplib2 but it is not installable
           Depends: python-six but it is not installable
           Depends: python-crypto (>= 2.6) but it is not installable
           Depends: python-setuptools but it is not installable
           Depends: sshpass but it is not installable
           Depends: python-pkg-resources but it is not installable
```

Shouldn't the process of installing ansible already install these packages? I'm kinda noob into this, but as I know, one package can list dependencies for other packages, so why these aren't installing automatically? Shouldn't debian also come with python at least?

I've put them into the apt-get script and it worket, but shouldn't it be automatic? What if a new ansible package in the ppa requires more packages? It'd break my dockerfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of overriding the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file using `>` you can append the text using `>>`.

So it will be something similar to the following.

```
RUN echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu trusty main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
&& apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 93C4A3FD7BB9C367 \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y ansible
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `-f` option to `apt-get install`, which attempts to fix broken dependencies. Prior to running `apt-get update` you may also want to run `apt-get clean` to clear the local apt repo. These worked for my Packer build that uses the Ansible provisioner.

Your code would become:

```
RUN echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list \
&& apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 93C4A3FD7BB9C367 \
&& apt-get autoclean \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -f ansible
```

For additional details I recommend [this excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/142808/246722) to the broader question, "How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?"

Answer (score 0):

**For currently supported versions of Ubuntu** You can update your system with **unsupported** packages from [this untrusted PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ansible/+archive/ubuntu/ansible) by adding ppa:ansible/ansible to your system's Software Sources.

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main
```

You can install ansible utilizing the following commands.

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install software-properties-common
$ sudo apt-add-repository --yes --update ppa:ansible/ansible
$ sudo apt install ansible
```

**Note that if you are using a version of Ubuntu prior to 18.04** there is no `-u` or `--update` switch for `apt-add-repository` so if that's your case leave the `--update` switch out of the 3rd line of code above.

Sources:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-ansible-on-ubuntu

`man apt-add-repository`